# File is getting downloaded twice in Java Jersey API

Tags: java, pdf, jersey, itext, html-to-pdf

I am using following code to download PDF from html contain my working fine but file is getting downloaded twice I tried to modify renderer behavior but still haven't got anything.

```
public Response downloadResumePdf(@PathParam("userId") String userId) throws IOException, DocumentException {
     String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String filePath = homePath + "/Downloads/Resume" + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate() + ".pdf";
        org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        String yourXhtmlContentAsString = "<h1>hi </h1>";
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(yourXhtmlContentAsString);
        renderer.layout();
        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filePath);
        renderer.createPDF(fos);
        fos.close();
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return Response
          .ok((Object) file)
          .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Resume" + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate() + ".pdf\"")
          .build();
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, it only downloads once for me. Are you calling this endpoint twice somewhere which makes it download twice?

Comment: @Mark in downloads folder same file is created twice

Comment: How is the same file created twice? Do they have different filenames?

Comment: @Mark I am using above mentioned code only

Comment: You're loading a file called `Resume2019-01-16.pdf` from your downloads folder to serve on your API, then you run your API locally and it will download to `Resume2019-01-16 (1).pdf`, is this the 'downloading twice' you mention? That there are now two files in the downloads folder? Or is it creating `Resume2019-01-16 (1).pdf`and `Resume2019-01-16 (2).pdf` when you go to that endpoint?

Comment: yes its two file created on Downloads folder but I  want only one file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186780/discussion-between-tejal-and-mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the duplication, as mentioned in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54216603/2587435), is because you are creating a "temporary" file when you create and write to the `FileOutputStream`.

The solution: you do not need to create a temporary file to handle the Download. Instead of creating a `FileOutputStream`, just use `StreamingOutput` and pass the `StreamingOutput`'s `OutputStream` to the `ITextRenderer#createPDF(OutputStream)` method.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getResumePdf(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {

    StreamingOutput entity = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) {
            try {
                ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
                String yourXhtmlContentAsString = "<h1>hi </h1>";
                renderer.setDocumentFromString(yourXhtmlContentAsString);
                renderer.layout();
                renderer.createPDF(output);
                output.flush();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    return Response.ok(entity)
         .header(...)
         .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The issue**

In your code you're generating a file which then will be served on your API. This file is created with `new java.io.FileOutputStream(filePath)` and is called `Resume2019-01-16.pdf` located in the `Downloads` folder.

Since you're running your API locally, when you go to your endpoint the browser will download the file you're serving to your `Downloads` folder. Since `Resume2019-01-16.pdf` already exists there the browser will name it `Resume2019-01-16 (1).pdf`.

Hence it looks like two files are being downloaded, but one is being generated by your code and the other one is *actually* downloaded.

**Fix**

Change the folder for the files you're serving and only the files that are actually downloaded will appear in your `Downloads` eg:

```
String filePath = homePath + "/Documents/Resume" + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate() + ".pdf";
```

Alternatively use some method to store your file in memory instead of creating a physical file and serve that instead.

Comment: one is being generated by your code and the other one is actually downloaded.this the problem which  I don't want I only want one file creation

Answer (score 0):

You shold use StreamingOutput instead of using File.

```
String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String filePath = homePath + "/Downloads/Resume" + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate() + ".pdf";

    org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    String yourXhtmlContentAsString = "<h1>hi </h1>";
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(yourXhtmlContentAsString);
    renderer.layout();

    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filePath);
    renderer.createPDF(fos);
    //fos.close();
    final File file = new File(filePath);

    StreamingOutput fileStream =  new StreamingOutput()
    {
        @Override
        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
        {
            try
            {

                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                output.write(data);
                output.flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new WebApplicationException("File Not Found. !!");
            }
        }
    };

   return Response
       .ok( fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
       .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Resume" + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate() + ".pdf\"")
       .build();
```

Comment: I tried above mentioned code still file is getting created twice

Comment: This is a poor implementation of the StreamingOutput and defeats the purpose of what it is for. You are reading the entire file into memory with `Files.readAllBytes()`.